# h:inputText not working with a4j:commandLink

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

`myBean` is in `request` scope.

```
<h:form id="indexFormID">
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true" layout="block">
    <h:inputText id="inputForHD" value="#{myBean.inputParam}"></h:inputText>
    <a4j:commandLink value="Submit" action="#{myBean.myMethod}" reRender="renderSuccess" process="indexFormID:inputForHD"></a4j:commandLink>
</a4j:outputPanel>


 <h:panelGroup id="renderSuccess">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.someBoolean}">
       //Some other JSF components go here          
    </h:panelGroup>
 </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

`MyBean` class definition:

```
private String inputParam;
//Getters and setters are there

public String myMethod()
{
    log.debug("~ Value of inputParam" +this.getInputParam()); //This is printing null value for inputParam 
    //when commandLink is clicked
    return null;
}
```

Why my `inputParam` is not getting set with the input parameters?

Comment: Is the mymethod getting called or not?

Comment: What are you processing in your getter/setter methods?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj `myMethod` is getting called. There is no problem in that. In the comment I have written that am getting `null` value for `initParam` inside `myMethod`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza There is no extra processing being done in getter/setter methods. They are just getters and setters.

Comment: The problem is that your component id is `formID:outputPanelID:inputTextID` and you're just sending `formID:inputTextID` which is an incorrect id.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: Where is the output panelId??? I just tested this, and I can trace the value like: indexFormID:inputForHD=sdfsdfsdf from the request map

Comment: See my updated answer. Should solve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found few issues with your approach:

```
<h:inputText id="inputForHD" value="#{myBean.inputParam}"></h:inputText>
```

You are already mapping the inputParam attribute with this bean, why have a new Id "inputForHD"

Use the inputParam itself, if you want to use inputForHD, you can pick the same from request Parameter map like.

```
String inputForHD = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("indexFormID:inputForHD");
```

Also as I mentioned previously wrap the output panel inside the and a4j panel e.g.

```
     <h:panelGroup id="renderSuccess">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{helloWorld.someBoolean}">
           //Some other JSF components go here
           <h:inputText id="inputForHDasdasd" value="#{helloWorld.inputParam}"></h:inputText>
        </h:panelGroup>
     </h:panelGroup>
```

This is working fine, let know if any issues.

Comment: Looks like `myBean.myMethod` is managing the value for `myBean.someBoolean` based on the value of `myBean.inputParam`, so is ok if `myBean.someBoolean` is `false` and then it becomes `true` (note that OP doesn't rerender the `h:panelGroup` instead the wrapper `UIContainer` `<a4j:outputPanel>`).

Comment: Yes that's what I think too, that's why I asked that it doesn't resolve to "false" after method, else it will not be rendered. I believe if the outer container is rerendered the inner components rerender by self. That's supposed to be the way.

Comment: The problem is that OP isn't sending the right ID for the `<h:inputText>` in the `process` attribute of `<a4j:commandLink>`. See my answer for a solution.

Comment: That I have already seen nor am I contradicting that. I was replying to your comment.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Tried with your updated answer. But, still am not getting the actual value entered. I am still getting `null` value. I even changed scope of myBean to `session` and changed `getRequestParameterMap` to `getSessionMap`. Even then it didn't work!

Comment: No need to convert to session scope, move back to request. 1. Remove the process tag attribute for now. 2. Put a debug pointer on myMethod, and paste the values for getRequestParameterMap 3. Share you updated JSF and Bean.